# Insert into mysql with php

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I have this piece of code, my user_account table gets populated but I am not getting anything inside my donor table. Can someone please tell me what could be the problem ? Thanks!

```
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, "INSERT INTO user_account(username, password) VALUES (?, ?);") or die("Can't prepare user_account query: " . mysqli_error($conn));
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $_POST['user'], $_POST['psw']);
mysqli_execute($stmt);
$stmt2 = mysqli_prepare($conn, "
    INSERT INTO donor (user_id, blood_id, first_name,last_name,email_add,gender, birthday, telephone, city, last_donation)
    SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID(), b.blood_id, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?
    FROM blood_type AS b
    WHERE b.Blood_group= ?") or die ("Can't prepare donor query: " . mysqli_error($conn));
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt2, "sssssssss", $_POST['fname'], $_POST['lname'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['gender'], $_POST['Birthday'], $_POST['Telephone'], $_POST['city'], $_POST['lastdonation'], $_POST['bloodgroup']);
    mysqli_execute($stmt2);
```

Comment: Have you checked your error logs?

Comment: 2016-04-15T16:19:47.177655Z 42 [Warning] Warning: Enabling keys got errno 0 on blood_bank_project.donor, retrying